# Apply custom formatting to each JSON property

Tags: c#, json.net, choetl

Does the ChoJSONWriter or Newtonsoft support apply custom formatting to each JSON property. After pulling my data from the datasource I would like apply the following format to each JSON record.

```
{
  "Place": "{0}",
  "SkuNumber": "SKU_{1}"
}
```

I can do it manually by going through each record and applying String.Format but I dont want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: can you pls tell us what approach (dynamic / POCO) you are using to create JSON file? sample code helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can add custom format to each member using Cinchoo ETL

**Dynamic Approach:**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var w = new ChoJSONWriter(sb)
    .WithField("Place")
    .WithField("SkuNumber", valueConverter: (o) => String.Format("SKU_{0}", o.ToNString()))
    )
{
    dynamic o1 = new ExpandoObject();
    o1.Place = 1;
    o1.SkuNumber = 100;

    w.Write(o1);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

**POCO:**

```
public class PlaceObj
{
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public int SkuNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**POCO Approach:**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var w = new ChoJSONWriter<PlaceObj>(sb)
    .WithField(m => m.SkuNumber, valueConverter: (o) => String.Format("SKU_{0}", o.ToNString()))
)
{
    PlaceObj o1 = new PlaceObj();
    o1.Place = "1";
    o1.SkuNumber = 100;

    w.Write(o1);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the solution needs to be generic as I do not know what fields will be returned and the list of fields are available only at runtime because the DataSource is a CSV file.

Comment: Can u post a sample code with input and expected output?